# When hfpclient is enabled in android's config.xml and then when trying to pair a device I am seeing a crash in the hfpclient's JNI interface

Tags: android, bluetooth, crash, java-native-interface, hfp

```
--- a/res/values/config.xml
+++ b/res/values/config.xml
@@ -17,7 +17,7 @@
     <bool name="profile_supported_a2dp_sink">false</bool>
     <bool name="profile_supported_hdp">true</bool>
     <bool name="profile_supported_hs_hfp">true</bool>
-    <bool name="profile_supported_hfpclient">false</bool>
+    <bool name="profile_supported_hfpclient">true</bool>
```

> 08-29 14:16:35.703  4697  4697 I crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.704  3147  3147 I /system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 3559
>   08-29 14:16:35.704  4697  4697 I crash_dump64: performing dump of process 3450 (target tid = 3559)
>   08-29 14:16:35.711  3636  3636 D StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.InstanceCountViolation: class com.android.settings.SubSettings; instances=2; limit=1
>   08-29 14:16:35.711  3636  3636 D StrictMode:   at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.722  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :
>
> ---
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.722  4697  4697 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Android/proline_basic_proto3/proline_basic_proto3:9/2.0.0-ga-rc4/root08230119:eng/dev-keys'
>   08-29 14:16:35.722  4697  4697 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
>   08-29 14:16:35.722  4697  4697 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
>   08-29 14:16:35.722  4697  4697 F DEBUG   : pid: 3450, tid: 3559, name: BT Service Call  >>> com.android.bluetooth <<<
>   08-29 14:16:35.723  4697  4697 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.723  4697  4697 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'java_vm_ext.cc:542] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void com.android.bluetooth.hfpclient.NativeInterface.onConnectionStateChanged(int, int, int, byte[]) on instance of java.lang.Class'
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.723  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000000de7  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000000000000008
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.723  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     x4  fefff69db9b60667  x5  fefff69db9b60667  x6  fefff69db9b60667  x7  7f7fffffffff7f7f
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.723  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     x8  0000000000000083  x9  0000f79eba2b7a68  x10 fffffff87ffffbdf  x11 0000000000000001
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.723  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     x12 0000f79ea06813[  172.909846] alloc_contig_range: [a7f00, a8285) PFNs busy
>   38  x13 ffffffffffffffff  x14 ffffffffff000000  x15 ffffffffffffffff
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.723  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000f79eba2f02c8  x17 0000f79eba22e2d8  [  172.929388] alloc_contig_range: [a7f00, a8285) PFNs busy
>   x18 0000f79ea0680b0a  x19 0000000000000d7a
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.723  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     x20 0000000000000de7  x21 0000000000000083  x22 0000f79eb32fd400  x23 0000f79e9e23c000
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.723  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     x24 0000000000000000  x25 0000000000000012  x26 0000000000000005  x27 0000f79eb9906c13
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.723  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     x28 0000f79eb9906ac7  x29 0000f79ea0681890
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.723  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     sp  0000f79ea0681850  lr  0000f79eba222a90  pc  0000f79eba222abc
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0000000000021abc  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+124)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 000000000046adb0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1208)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0000000000008d2c  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+724)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00000000002e8908  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1656)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00000000002e8a7c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, std::__va_list)+108)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00000000000fd5f8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+144)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00000000001015a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::CheckMethodAndSig(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+1920)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00000000000ffcb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+756)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 00000000000ed5d4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+84)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 0000000000017ec0  /system/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so (_JNIEnv::CallVoidMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+120)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 000000000001d71c  /system/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so (android::connection_state_cb(RawAddress const*, bthf_client_connection_state_t, unsigned int, unsigned int)+268)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 000000000012b8d8  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (btif_hf_client_upstreams_evt(unsigned short, char*)+3488)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 0000000000116124  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (bt_jni_msg_ready(void*)+116)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.765  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #13 pc 0000000000096aec  /system/lib64/libchrome.so (base::debug::TaskAnnotator::RunTask(char const*, base::PendingTask*)+244)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.766  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #14 pc 00000000000b0388  /system/lib64/libchrome.so (base::MessageLoop::RunTask(base::PendingTask*)+416)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.766  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #15 pc 00000000000b0634  /system/lib64/libchrome.so (base::MessageLoop::DeferOrRunPendingTask(base::PendingTask)+52)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.766  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #16 pc 00000000000b0a7c  /system/lib64/libchrome.so (base::MessageLoop::DoWork()+380)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.766  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #17 pc 00000000000b1e44  /system/lib64/libchrome.so (base::MessagePumpDefault::Run(base::MessagePump::Delegate*)+180)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.766  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #18 pc 00000000000b0070  /system/lib64/libchrome.so (base::MessageLoop::RunHandler()+112)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.766  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #19 pc 00000000000cd200  /system/lib64/libchrome.so (base::RunLoop::Run()+136)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.766  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #20 pc 0000000000114334  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (run_message_loop(void*)+284)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.766  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #21 pc 0000000000232874  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (work_queue_read_cb(void*)+92)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.766  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #22 pc 0000000000230a90  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (run_reactor(reactor_t*, int)+320)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.766  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #23 pc 0000000000230924  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (reactor_start(reactor_t*)+84)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.766  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #24 pc 00000000002322f8  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (run_thread(void*)+184)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.766  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #25 pc 0000000000083194  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.766  4697  4697 F DEBUG   :     #26 pc 00000000000233bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
>
> 08-29 14:16:35.776  4697  4697 I crash_dump64: type=1400 audit(0.0:53): avc: denied { read } for name="btopp.db-shm" dev="mmcblk2p12" ino=758 scontext=u:r:crash_dump:s0

Once the flag to start the service for hfpclient is enabled in Bluetooth Apk of Android and then when the image with the flag enabled in loaded onto the device and when pairing is initiated with the device, I am seeing a crash in the JNI interface.

The main reason I could see from the crash logs is this:
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void com.android.bluetooth.hfpclient.NativeInterface.onConnectionStateChanged(int, int, int, byte[]) on instance of java.lang.Class'

```
@@ -350,6 +368,14 @@ static bthf_client_callbacks_t sBluetoothHfpClientCallbacks = {
 static void classInitNative(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz) {
   method_onConnectionStateChanged =
       env->GetMethodID(clazz, "onConnectionStateChanged", "(III[B)V");
+  if(method_onConnectionStateChanged == 0)
+  {
+         ALOGE("%s : FAILED TO INIT OBJ",__func__);
+  }
+  else
+  {
+         ALOGE("%s : INIT OBJ",__func__);
+  }
```

I am able to verify from the above code that the MethodID is assigned to the variable.

```
@@ -68,13 +72,27 @@ static void connection_state_cb(const RawAddress* bd_addr,
                                 bthf_client_connection_state_t state,
                                 unsigned int peer_feat,
                                 unsigned int chld_feat) {
+  std::shared_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex> lock(callbacks_mutex);
   CallbackEnv sCallbackEnv(__func__);
-  if (!sCallbackEnv.valid()) return;
+  if (!sCallbackEnv.valid() || !mCallbacksObj)
+  {
+         ALOGE("****ERRORR****");
+         return;
+  }

   ScopedLocalRef<jbyteArray> addr(sCallbackEnv.get(), marshall_bda(bd_addr));
+
   if (!addr.get()) return;

   ALOGD("%s: state %d peer_feat %d chld_feat %d", __func__, state, peer_feat, chld_feat);
+  if(method_onConnectionStateChanged == 0)
+{
+        ALOGE("%s : FAILED TO INIT OBJ",__func__);
+}
+else
+{
+        ALOGE("%s : INIT OBJ",__func__);
+}
   sCallbackEnv->CallVoidMethod(mCallbacksObj, method_onConnectionStateChanged,
                                (jint)state, (jint)peer_feat, (jint)chld_feat,
                                addr.get());
```

Also, I have verified the same in the place where the CallVoidMethod() is called and even there I could see that the method_onConnectionStateChanged has not lost its scope.

So, I am not sure what is causing this error:
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void com.android.bluetooth.hfpclient.NativeInterface.onConnectionStateChanged(int, int, int, byte[]) on instance of java.lang.Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same issue and found that is was actually fixed in android: see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/c8e910d0393d2d7f3bf46d90746819d024ec7510

Also note that if [JNI checks](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#extended-checking) are not enabled (eg: build in user mode) the issue will not occur.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will try it out and let you know.